# jQuery .each() .hover() slideshow

Tags: jquery, timer, hover, slideshow, setinterval

So I'm afraid this is another one of those slideshow questions that clutters up Stack, but I'm pretty new to jQuery and javascript and wanted to have a go at writing something myself rather than using plugins etc. What I need is pretty straight forward stuff:

Couple of boxes containing images with a class name of .slideshow, thus:

```
<div class="box b1">
  <a href="#" title="Project Title" class="slideshow 2000">
    <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item">
    <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="box b2">
  <a href="#" title="Project Title" class="slideshow 2000">
    <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item">
    <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item">
  </a>
</div>
```

Each one is looping round the images happily then I hover on it and it pauses, then it continues on mouseout... Easy, right? ......

My jQuery currently looks like this (I'm in no-conflict mode...hence jQuery):

```
jQuery(".slideshow").each(function(){
    var $this_s;
    var $that = jQuery(this);

    $that.find("img:gt(0)").hide(); //hide all images after first one

    function slide($this_s){
        $this_s.find(":first-child").hide().next('img').show()
        .end().appendTo($that);
    }
    var int = $that.attr("class");
    int = int.replace("slideshow ", "");

    interval = setInterval(slide($that), int);
    $that.hover(function(){
        interval = clearInterval(interval);
    },function(){
        interval = setInterval(slide($that), int);             
    });
});
```

At the moment it's doing a peculiar thing where on MouseEnter it does nothing, then MouseLeave it changes to the next image. I feel I'm almost there, I just can't work out why setInterval isn't doing it's thang!

I have tried it without my funny little get interval from classname thing, and stuck a number inthere instead but still no joy.

Any help (again) would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Aha, I think you're onto something. I wanted to try and keep the function separate from setInterval to save me from writing it twice, but as it's only one line of code it's fine I suppose. I don't think I've quite got the hang of function scope yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter (the delay) that **[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)** uses an int value to set it, you may want to consider using `parseInt(int)` when setting it, like so:

```
int = int.replace("slideshow ","");
int = parseInt(int);
```

or

```
interval = setInterval(slide($that), parseInt(int));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, I realise it's probably not the most elegant solution. How would you code it?